# How to disable/hide the submit function when the form is submitted?

Tags: drupal-6

I have created form with a submit button. I want when I click on the submit button then the submit button should hide or disable.

How could i do this? Any Idea??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439413/submit-button-grayed-out/6439475

Comment: but its for simple php and I am using drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/hide_submit